# Can't run scrapy command on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, scrapy

I'm trying to get the `scrapy` command to run when I type `heroku run scrapy`. However I just get `bash: scrapy: command not found`.

I have Scrapy in my requirements.txt file as well as a scrapy.cfg file. I can run `scrapy` locally just fine.

Anybody know what I'm possibly missing here?

Comment: were you able to figure it out? stuck with the same problem now